# How to improve curve fitting in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, levenberg-marquardt

I am using `lsqcurvefit` function of matlab to fit o the calculated values by a 'function' to observed data and optimizing two parameters of 'function'. After running the code I get optimized values of parameters but fit between calculated/simulated curve and observed curve is quite bade as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqc3l.png). I have tried using Marquardt Levenberg algorithm as well as Reflective region and tried reducing function tolerance but of no avail. What can I do to make simulated curve look more closely as the observed curve or is there a software for curve fitting with GUI so that I can manually change my simulated curve to make it look similar to observed curve?
The code I am using is

```
function wtfinal = fst(para,tes)
x = 45; k = para(1);  b = 2;   S = para(2); D = k*2/S; tes = 1:998;
g_vecrow = (xlsread('signaal 1.xlsx','signal','D2:D999'))';
g_vec = g_vecrow-g_vecrow(1) ;
t_vec = tes.*5;
for i = 2:998
    t = t_vec(i);
    g = g_vec(i);
tow = 0:5:t-1;
f = g.*(t - tow).^(-3/2).*exp(-x^2./(4*D*(t - tow)));
wt(i) = ((1/D)^(1/2)* x)/(2 * sqrt(pi))* trapz(tow,f);   
end
wtfinal = wt + 147.902;
end
```

and using this function as

```
    clear all; close all; clc;
ydata = (xlsread('signaal 1.xlsx','signal','C2:C999'))';
tes = 1:998;
x0 = [0.0327 0.00172];
  lb = [];
  ub = [];
opts = optimset('Algorithm', 'levenberg-marquardt');
[newpara,resnorm,~,exitflag,output]=lsqcurvefit(@fst,x0,tes,ydata,lb,ub,opts)
figure
plot(tes,ydata)
hold on
simulated=fst(newpara,tes);
plot(tes,simulated,'r')
```

The data file 'signaal 1' can be obtained from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qym5fulpj6uzgg2/signaal%201.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: If that's the result of your curve fitting it seems something's gone awry. Can you post a working example?

Comment: My 'function' requires 998 data points as one of input parameter, can u please tell me how can I give you working example? Or should I simply write the code I used.

Comment: @AtherCheema you have to post the code! If you want to post the data, upload it to somewhere like google drive and share the link. But I would suggest that you first test your code on simple simulated data. Try a simple quadratic function with a bit of noise and see what your code produces with that. Also, with `lsqcurvefit` you are fitting a structured model right (i.e. finding parameters), so you also need to tell us what your model is.

Comment: It may sound obvious, but are you sure that your model will actually fit your data? i.e. try first to generate some sample data using your model, add some noise, and then check if `lsqcurvefit` can fit the model to the simulated data, returning the original parameters.

Comment: @zelanix    This is what I want to test/prove through this whole exercise. Here I used one solution of heat equation (by fourier transform) and coded it. I have used the same data for another solution of heat equation (with same boundary and initial conditions using laplace transform)  which uses same input parameters and the result is  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a5vj0upqwggng5r/River%20to%20B2_1.tif?dl=0). As you can see here simulated curves are though not perfect but better than the ones that I got.  These curves are not obtained by `lsqcurvefit` but the solution is coded in Fortran.

Comment: @Dan My model uses input of waves in a river and tries to produce resulting changes at some distance x. Above data uses actual wave in a river. But [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2gzacxtwonm5yle/sine%20wave.tif?dl=0) I have tried to used an ideal sine wave (artificial) as input in my model and it seems that there is literally no change in simulated curve as compared to input sine wave. Does this mean that my mathematical model is not realistic or what does it mean?

Comment: @Dan But interestingly [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6ac4shrj7d9v9j/sine%20sine.tif?dl=0) I used 'observed' data as well a sine wave but of lesser amplitude and it shows that (mathematical) model does affect/modify 'input' to make it similar to the observed one. By the way I did carry out sensitivity analysis to check the effect of different parameters of model on model output (simulated curve ).